# What favor does Joker ask Batman in the Telltale series?

Tags: batman-the-telltale-series

I chose to promise to the Joker that I will return the favor for his help in getting me out. But even after completing the whole game, I couldn't see any option to meet the Joker, other than see him once in the ending.

What favor was Joker asking? Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

I played through the entire game once again, choosing only those options that I had not chosen in my first playthrough.

I managed to make sure I once again promised to return the favour to Joker.

But, nothing seems to lead me to any actual event where the Joker asks the favour.

I must say that this was a pointless part in the otherwise okay game plot.

EDIT: Or it may be continued in the possible season 2 of the game. Source: [Movie Pilot](https://moviepilot.com/p/batman-the-telltale-series-season-2/4183567). But a season 2 is not in the works as of now.

Comment: I assumed this was something that will be in the sequel.

Comment: @Adeese I don't think a sequel is in the works as of now.

Comment: I know that one hasn't been announced yet. To me it seemed like leaving a hint for what is to come in the future, assuming another game is made.